# How to cycle with an array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, stored-procedures, while-loop

I'd like to create a stored procedure or a normal query with values passed with an array.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc() 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cont INTEGER; 
    DECLARE var ARRAY; 
    SET cont = 0;
    SET var = ("hi", "hello", "good", ...)

    WHILE cont < 12 DO 
        SELECT * FROM tablex
        WHERE name = var[cont];
        SET cont = cont + 1; 
    END WHILE; 
END;
```

Obviously this is will not work, but I'd like to know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to do it without stored routine -

```
SET @arr = 'hi,hello,good'; -- your array

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablex
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET (name, @arr); -- calculate count
```

Answer (score 12):

Neither of existing answers worked for me, so I ended up implementing my very own (and very first) MySQL procedure.

```
PROCEDURE db.loop_through_array()
BEGIN
  DECLARE var varchar(150) DEFAULT 'hi,hello,good';
  DECLARE element varchar(150);

  WHILE var != '' DO
    SET element = SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, ',', 1);      
    SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE name = element;
    
    IF LOCATE(',', var) > 0 THEN
      SET var = SUBSTRING(var, LOCATE(',', var) + 1);
    ELSE
      SET var = '';
    END IF;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: The answer from Devart is very efficient for the example. In my case, I am looking to add accounts , usernames, passords and the same set of permissions.  The solution from Neurotransmitter works well for this case.

Comment: Would this be possible to make tablex as variable from element?
When I try to do the same, mysql think its a table and says table schema.element doesnt exist. How to do the same with variable as a table and var would contain definition of all tables?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cont INTEGER; 
    SET cont = 0;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE array_table (idx INT, value VARCHAR(20));
    INSERT INTO array_table (idx, value) VALUES (1,"hi"),(2,"hello"),(3,"good"),...;
    WHILE cont < 12 DO 
        SELECT * FROM tablex
        WHERE name IN (SELECT value FROM array_table WHERE idx = cont);
        SET cont = cont + 1; 
    END WHILE; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

an example of `WHILE` loop inside stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS WhileLoopProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE WhileLoopProc()
      BEGIN
              DECLARE x  INT;
              DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
              SET x = 1;
              SET str =  '';
              WHILE x  <= 5 DO
                          SET  str = CONCAT(str,x,',');
                          SET  x = x + 1; 
              END WHILE;
              SELECT str;
      END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

you can check [this article](http://kathyravan.blogspot.com/2009/02/arrays-in-mysql-stored-procedures.html) for examples of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases don't do arrays, they do scalars, rows and tables. SQL is largely a declarative, rather than procedural, language.

To count entries in a table, use the [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) aggregate function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tablex
  WHERE name IN ("hi", "hello", "good", ...)
```

If you need to handle a variable number of values to match against in a single statement, you can create a temporary table to hold the values instead of using `IN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tablex
  JOIN names ON tablex.name=names.name
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I don't need to count entries in a table but, instead, to cycle a select statement for each array entry.

Comment: @Davide: What do you mean by "cycle a select statement"? Please make the [example](http://sscce.org/) in your question complete by including sample table schema (as a `CREATE TABLE` statement), data (as an `INSERT ... INTO` statement) and desired results.

Comment: As in a programming language <br />
    x = new Array("a", "b", "c");

Comment: @Davide: do you mean "loop"? A loop isn't what you need, that's just your [solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to some other problem you've yet to describe. Edit your question and explain what you [really need](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal). SQL isn't really a programming language, it's a declarative data language. It has procedural elements, but these are tacked-on and should never be the primary means of expression.

Answer (score -1):

If you can create a table to store the array values you can do it without writing a loop. Use in() operator.

```
CREATE TABLE test_strings (element CHAR(6));
INSERT INTO  test_strings (element) VALUES ('hi'),('hello'),('good');

SELECT * FROM tablex t
    WHERE name IN(SELECT element FROM test_strings)
    ORDER BY t.name;
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess that you just want to:

```
SELECT * FROM tablex
WHERE name IN ('hi', 'hello', 'good', ...)
```

Do you have a problem with how to pass an array to a procedure?

Comment: The problem is that I need to cycle for each array entry.