# How to create a user defined variable that can be used in a set expression?

Tags: mysql

I would like to do this

```
set @a =(1,2,3);
select * from mytable where somefield in @a;
```

But mysql does not like it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this

```sql
SET @a = '1,2,3';
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(somefield, @a) > 0;
```

**Note:** This will effectively cause a full scan.

---

IMHO you better off without user variables containing strings

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable t JOIN
(
  SELECT 1 somefield UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3
) q
    ON t.somefield = q.somefield;
```

---

One more option is to leverage dynamic SQL

```sql
SET @a = '1,2,3';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somefield IN(', @a, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d8d5/3)** demo for all queries

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using temporary tables, as in this question:
[How can I simulate an array variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176709/how-can-i-simulate-an-array-variable-in-mysql)

Or you can use [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) as in this question:
[how to set an array as a mysql user variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424969/how-to-set-an-array-as-a-mysql-user-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @a = '1,2,3';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM test WHERE `user` IN(', @a, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0616/5)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done but with proper syntax and prepare statement, likethis:

```
set @a =1,2,3;
select * from mytable where somefield in (@a);


set @crt=concat("select * from mytable where somefield in ",concat('(',@a,')'),";"); 

prepare smnt from @crt;
EXECUTE smnt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE smnt;
```